# How to index same doc in different indices with different routing

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

I need to be able to index the same document in different indexes with different routing value.

Basically the problem to solve is to be able to calculate complex aggregations about payment information from the perspective of payer and collector. For example, "payments made / received in the last 15 days grouped by status"

I was wondering how we can achieve this using ElasticSearch bulk api.

Is it possible to achieve this without generating redundancy in the ndjson? Something like this for example:

```sh
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_1", "_id" : "1", "routing": "1234" } }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_2", "_id" : "1", "routing": "5678" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

I looked for documentation but I didn't find a place that explain this.

Answer (score 0):

By only using the bulk API, you'll need to repeat the document each time.

Another way of doing it is to bulk-index the documents into the first index and then using the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) you can create the second index with a different routing value for each document.

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_1", "_id" : "1", "routing": "1234" } }
{ "field1" : "value1", "routing2": "5678" }
```

And then you can reindex into a second index using the second routing value (that you need to store in the document somehow

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test_1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test_2"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._routing = ctx._source.routing2",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

That way, you only index the data once using the bulk API, which will roughly take half the time than when doubling all documents, and then by leveraging the Reindex API all the data will be reindexed internally (i.e. without the added network latency of sending the potentially big payload)